# Vue list not displaying the keys of a javascript dictionary?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use a v-for element to display the keys of a Javascript dictionary in a list. The dictionary starts blank, but keys and values are added based on a API call. The data is structured something like that below. (I JSON.stringified it to visualize the data, but the original javascript object is a dictionary titled fullFileList.)

```
fullFileList{
  "8-27.TXT.rtf": {
    "textbody": "Lots of text.",
    "filetitle": "8-27.TXT.rtf",
    "entities": [
      {
        "name": "Mario Sartori",
        "type": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Linda Grey",
        "type": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Julia",
        "type": "Person"
      }
    ]
  },
  "8-28.TXT.rtf": {
    "textbody": "Also lots of text.",
    "filetitle": "8-28.TXT.rtf",
    "entities": [
      {
        "name": "Maine Health Foundation",
        "type": "Organization"
      },
      {
        "name": "Grzesiak",
        "type": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jim Williams",
        "type": "Person"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I init the Vue this way:

```
var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#all',
   data: {
       files: fullFileList
   }
})
```

And my HTML is like this:

```
  <ul id="all" class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
      <li v-for="(value,key) in files" >
        <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">
        {{ key }} </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

No list elements appear at any point. What's going wrong?

EDIT: To clarify, this is a sample of how data is added to the fullFileList dictionary variable:

The original variable is defined like so at the top of the javascript file:

```
fullFileList = {}
```

And keys and values are added like this:

```
  basefilename = path.basename(fileNames[loadFile])

  fullFileList[basefilename] = {}
  fullFileList[basefilename]['textbody'] =  result['html']
  fullFileList[basefilename]['filetitle'] = basefilename
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your object assignment valid. You are missing an assignment to the object `let fullFileList = ...` When this is done, the list of files display.

```js
let fullFileList = {
  "8-27.TXT.rtf": {
    "textbody": "Lots of text.",
    "filetitle": "8-27.TXT.rtf",
    "entities": [{
        "name": "Mario Sartori",
        "type": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Linda Grey",
        "type": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Julia",
        "type": "Person"
      }
    ]
  },
  "8-28.TXT.rtf": {
    "textbody": "Also lots of text.",
    "filetitle": "8-28.TXT.rtf",
    "entities": [{
        "name": "Maine Health Foundation",
        "type": "Organization"
      },
      {
        "name": "Grzesiak",
        "type": "Person"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jim Williams",
        "type": "Person"
      }
    ]
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#all',
  data: {
    files: fullFileList
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {display: none !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul id="all" class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
  <li v-for="(value,key) in files">
    <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">
        {{ key }} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The original variable is defined like so: 

    `fullFileList = {}`

And keys and values are added like this: 

      `fullFileList[basefilename] = {}
      fullFileList[basefilename]['textbody'] =  result['html']
      fullFileList[basefilename]['filetitle'] = basefilename`

How do I change my object assignment in this case?

Comment: please put the example of how your `fullFileList` is built within the question so we can better help you out.

Comment: The example is up there now. Thanks!

Comment: In your example you are not defining `let` or `var`, `fullFileList = {}` should be `let fullFileList = {}` or `var fullFileList = {}`

Comment: Adding `var` or `let` doesn't seem to help. Might it have something to do with this? 

[https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats](`Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method. For example, given:

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    userProfile: {
      name: 'Anika'
    }
  }
})`)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error on `fullFileList{} rather fullFileList = {}`

You can also make fullFileList an array.

```
    fullFileList = [
      {"8-27.TXT.rtf": {
        "textbody": "Lots of text.",
        "filetitle": "8-27.TXT.rtf",
        "entities": [
          {
            "name": "Mario Sartori",
            "type": "Person"
          },
          {
            "name": "Linda Grey",
            "type": "Person"
          },
          {
            "name": "Julia",
            "type": "Person"
          }
        ]
      }
},
      {"8-28.TXT.rtf": {
        "textbody": "Also lots of text.",
        "filetitle": "8-28.TXT.rtf",
        "entities": [
          {
            "name": "Maine Health Foundation",
            "type": "Organization"
          },
          {
            "name": "Grzesiak",
            "type": "Person"
          },
          {
            "name": "Jim Williams",
            "type": "Person"
          }
        ]
      }
}
    ]
```

Comment: `v-for` will loop through an object too

Comment: Once `fullFileList` is assigned the Object with "=", the original code works